# WordPress Plugin doesn't work with own Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, contact-form

I am using Contact Form 7 on my site and have issues displaying the datepicker on IE and Firefox. Chrome works fine.

I downloaded the Plugin Contact Form 7 IE DatePicker and Number Spinner Fix and activated it on my site, but it seems like my Theme isn't loading the plugin files so the Plugin doesn't work.

I already tried to put the .js scripts manually into the footer but still no results.

Link to the site: http://www.hotel-zur-traube.eu/language/en/booking/

Hope anyone can help.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your source code you are loading Bootstrap.js (line 25) before of jQuery (line 26) and in fact in your console you have the error

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: Changed it, but still there is no datepicker showing up in Firefox and IE. In the footer there isn't any .js script loaded although the plugin is activated